# In the last blog section, nth-child is not happening

Tags: html, css, sass

```
 <div class="blog-card">

            <div class="blog-card__item blog">
                <div class="blog-card__img">
                    <img class="" src="./assests/img/2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="blog-card__content"></div>
```

blog-card__img I need to do div's nth-child(2), which has this class, but it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your idea. Do you want to modify the .blog-card__img of the 2nd .blog-card?

- It won't work because there is still an H4 tag on the same level as the classes .blog-card
- To do this, put all the .blog-card classes in a div and style the .blog-card__img classes.

Last Blog

```
<div class="blog-card-container">
    <div class="blog-card">
        <div class="blog-card__item blog">
            <div class="blog-card__img ">
                <img class="" src="./assests/img/1.jpg"
                alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-card__content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-card">
        <div class="blog-card__item blog">
            <div class="blog-card__img ">
                <img class="" src="./assests/img/2.jpg"
                alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-card__content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-card">
        <div class="blog-card__item blog">
            <div class="blog-card__img ">
                <img class="" src="./assests/img/3.jpg"
                alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-card__content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-card">
        <div class="blog-card__item blog">
            <div class="blog-card__img ">
                <img class="" src="./assests/img/4.jpg"
                alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-card__content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS will look like this:

```
<style>
.blog-card-container .blog-card:nth-child(2) .blog-card__img {
  // Your Style
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd div tag is not blog-card__img, replace blog-card__content with blog-card__img or add the following:

```
<div class="blog-card">

        <div class="blog-card__item blog">
            <div class="blog-card__img">
                <img class="" src="./assests/img/2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-card__img blog-card__content"></div>
```

Comment: but there are 3 blog-card elements and 2. I want to give a different feature to the blog-card__image of the blog-card element

Comment: Can you send me the full code and explain it better? I think I still don't understand what you mean

Comment: can you give me the GitHub mail?

Comment: I invited you, and when you look at the code, you'll know what I want to do.